# Trying to resize TextBox + font size in text box with C# and WPF, can only do one or the other

Tags: c#, wpf, viewbox

I'm trying to resize the textbox and the text inside of the textbox when the window is resized.  I seem to be able to do one or the other, but not both at once.

Resizing the textbox works, but I can't resize the text inside:
[image: original size]
[image: resized]

Code for above example:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

Or resizing the font works, but I can't make the textbox fill the viewbox I'm using:
[image: original]
[image: resized]

Code for above example:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

Using Stretch="Fill" (on the right track, but I'd rather keep it uniform, and UniformToFill does something weird that I can't even see what's going on)
[image: Fill]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use converter.

```
public class FontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double actualHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        int fontSize = (int)(actualHeight * .5);
        return fontSize;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
....
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FontSizeConverter x:Key="fontSizeCon" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>     
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeCon}}"/>
    </Grid>      
</Grid>
...
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am still learning WPF and had to look some things up to even see what you did here.  Not only did I get a working solution, but I also learned some stuff researching that solution.

Comment: Also, just wanted to add that it took me awhile to figure out because I'm not of the habit of building the project before running inside of the IDE.  Without building, it was not seeing the namespace, just an FYI in addition to my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this be suitable?

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform">
            <TextBox Text="some text"></TextBox>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This does the same thing for me as my second example.